# Laravel Closure Request

Tags: laravel, request

Assalamualaikum guys, i have some problems with my code. i tried to make search by using request parameters on laravel. and here is my code views.

```
$maintenance->with([
          'user_post' => function($query, Request $request){
                if($request->has('searchBy') && $request->has('searchQuery'))
                {
                    $parse_query = explode('.',$request->query('searchBy'));
                    $is_user = $parse_query[0] == 'user_post'? true : false;
                    if($is_user)
                    {
                        $query->where($parse_query[1],'LIKE','%'.$request->query('searchQuery').'%');
                    }
                }
            },
            'dt_project'
        ]);
```

when i tried to execute on browser, it return

> 1/1) ErrorException
>   Undefined variable: request

what should i do? thanks to the moon and back. hehehe

Comment: Are you sure this is the error block? Please show the *entire* error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, change your line 2 to:

```
'user_post' => function($query) use($request){
```

explanation:

`Request $request` can only be used in controller functions like:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //code here
}
```

in order to pass the `$request` parameter inside another function, use `use` (this is also known as [variable inheriting](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user= User::with(['roles' => function($query) use($request){
                                                   ^^^
            $query->where('roles.id', $request['role_id'])->first();

        }])->get();
}
```

Comment: for future SOers who might stumble upon this answer, please provide further explanation on why this works.

Comment: no problem dimas .
wreigh, all done. I tried my best to explain. :)